# Pasting text into PDF while keeping format

Tags: pdf

I've got a chunk of text with mixed formatting (bold, italic, underlined), all of which is in the same font luckily. The thing is, when I copy+paste text from the Word document to a PDF using Adobe Acrobat, it instantly loses all formatting

Do you guys know how to keep text formatting while copy + pasting???

Thank you!

Comment: Not an answer to your query, but how about saving as PDF in Word and then editing the file in Acrobat instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Acrobat Pro and you have the plug-in for Word you can export the Word Doc as a PDF then open it in Acrobat Pro and select the object with the arrow tool and copy and paste it into the other PDF.

**Rich Text in Acrobat Forms:**
If you're trying to copy and paste type into a PDF's form field in Acrobat Pro, you'll need to make the form field a `rich text` field (under properties for the field).

[image: Rich Text]

Comment: Pefect, that works!!!